# laravel counting two different table, after getting two values convert in single value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

laravel counting two different table, example(table-A,table-B) after counting we get two different values that two values example(table-A=10,table-B=10) how to sum that value example(table-A=10 + table-B=10), total value 20
and pass that in view

```
public function index() 
{
 $table-A = A::all()->count(); 
$table-B = B::all()->count(); 
return view('home',compact('table-A','table-B')) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this that way:

```
public function index()
{
    $tableA = A::all()->count();
    $tableB = B::all()->count();
    $sum = $tableA + $tableB;
    return view('home',compact('tableA','tableB', 'sum'))
}
```